# How to collect text nodes at same element level?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

below is example xml.
I'm studying xml.etree.ElementTree module not lxml.

```
<data>
    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>  
            <BBB>is</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>test1</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This is test</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

   <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>222222</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>333333</BBB>
        </CCC>      
    </AAA>  

    <AAA>
        <BBB>
            <CCC>This is test</CCC>
        </BBB>
    </AAA>
</data>
```

I'm trying to collect all texts of BBB under CCC under AAA element.
but i have no idea why it doesnt work. there is no error when it starts but texts are not collected.
i wonder why this code doesn't work well.

```
BBB_collect = ''.join(BBB.itertext())
```

please check below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

f1 = open ("C:\\test\\Data.xml","r",encoding="utf=8")
f2 = open ("C:\\test\\output.xml","wt",encoding="utf=8")
doc = ET.parse("C:\\test\\Data.xml")
root = doc.getroot()
a = 0

try:
    while True :
        AAA = root.findall('AAA')[a]
        for CCC in AAA.findall('CCC'):
            for BBB in CCC.findall('BBB'):
                BBB_collect = ''.join(BBB.itertext())
                print(BBB_collect)
        print('===============')
        a = a+1
except IndexError :
    pass
```

Could you give ma any advice ? What's wrong with it ?

Ultimately, this is my goal below.

```
<data>
    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>Thisistest1</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This is test</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>222222333333</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>  

    <AAA>
        <BBB>
            <CCC>This is test</CCC>
        </BBB>
    </AAA>
</data>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

**Demo:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(data)   

for AAA in doc.findall('AAA'):
    bText = ""
    for CCC in AAA.findall('CCC'):
        for BBB in CCC.findall('BBB'):
            bText += BBB.text
    print(bText)
```

**Output:**

```
Thisistest1
This is test
222222333333
This is test
```

Comment: Great Rakesh ! That's what i want. I think the way i choose is wrong. i should have used string not parse.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
try:
    while True :
        AAA = root.findall('AAA')[a]
        BBB_text = ""
        for CCC in AAA.findall('CCC'):
            for BBB in CCC.findall('BBB'):
                BBB_text = BBB_text+BBB.text
        print(BBB_text)
        print('===============')
        a = a+1
except IndexError :
    pass
```

Comment: above all thanks for your help. but it's same result. no error but doesn't collect nodes.